# Can't solve error: 'You can't specify target table 'categories' for update in FROM clause'

Tags: sql, database, error-handling, mariadb

Basically I'm trying to make this query to my Database:

```
DELETE FROM categories
WHERE id = (SELECT id FROM categories WHERE name = 'cat1');
```

Then I get this error:
(Error: 'You can't specify target table 'categories' for update in FROM clause')

This query is supposed to delete a category row based on its id, but I don't know its id, I only know its name so that's what I came up with..
How can I make this work out?

I tried modifiying the query and using variables but in MariaDB is a little bit overwhelming for me to do, I'm not that experienced with this Database.
For instance I was trying to save the SELECT query result in a variable then remove the row with that variable, but I can't find out how to do it.

Comment: Why not just do: DELETE FROM categories WHERE name = 'cat1';

Comment: Why can't you just have the where clause be `name = 'cat1'`?

Comment: Okay that's right, you helped me

Comment: Thanks, I didn't think about it xD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some people have suggested:

```
DELETE FROM categories
WHERE name = 'cat1';
```

However, that does not meet the criterion:

> supposed to delete a category row based on its id

The `IN` keyword will allow an inner query to retrieve id values which the outer query can use.

```
DELETE FROM categories
WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM categories WHERE name = 'cat1');
```

If id is a unique key of *categories*, then those two SQL updates should behave identically.

If *categories* had multiple records with the same id value:

- The first update will delete only records with name "cat1".
- The second update would delete all records with an id that matches at least one record with name "cat1".